# sql_exporter - column(s) ["serviceRequest1" "serviceResponseCode1"] missing from query result

Tags: prometheus

I have issues with [sql_exporter](https://github.com/free/sql_exporter). A very simple SQL query does not work.

DB query and output (SQL Server 2022)

```
SELECT [serviceRequest], [serviceResponseCode]
FROM [ccc].[bbb].[aaa]
WHERE [serviceDisplayName] = 'UploadDoc'
```

Output: URI and HTTP_CODE

```
http://example.org/OTCS/llisapi.dll 200
http://example.org/OTCS/llisapi.dll 200
http://example.org/OTCS/llisapi.dll 200
http://example.org/OTCS/llisapi.dll 200
```

Very simple: I wish to make a rule if not 200 and return the HTTP code and URI

Config

```
global:
  scrape_timeout_offset: 500ms
  min_interval: 0s
  max_connections: 3
  max_idle_connections: 3

target:
  data_source_name: 'sqlserver://x:xx:1433'
  collectors: [YYY]

collector_files: 
  - "YYY.collector.yml"
```

and

```
collector_name: YYY

metrics:
  - metric_name: upload_document
    type: gauge
    help: 'Upload Document with REST API'
    key_labels:
      - serviceRequest1
      - serviceResponseCode1
    value_label: UploadDocHTTPcode
    values: 
      - serviceRequest
      - serviceResponseCode
    query: |
      SELECT [serviceRequest], [serviceResponseCode]
      FROM [ccc].[bbb].[aaa]
      WHERE [serviceDisplayName] = 'UploadDoc'
```

Error

```
I0831 09:31:17.132976    6824 main.go:67] Listening on :9399
I0831 09:31:23.247900    6824 sql.go:88] Database handle successfully opened with driver sqlserver.
I0831 09:31:23.280905    6824 promhttp.go:38] Error gathering metrics: [from Gatherer #1] [, collector="YYY", query="upload_document"] column(s) ["serviceRequest1" "serviceResponseCode1"] missing from query result
```

Comment: Your post is missing a question. I understand that you imply that you need help with mentioned error, but explicit question will help us address your situation better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation for sql_exporter is rather lacking, but general idea can be found [here](https://github.com/free/sql_exporter/blob/master/documentation/sql_exporter.yml):

- `key_labels` are expected to be names of columns to be used as labels in created metric. In your case it should be a single `serviceRequest`.
- `values` - names of columns that contain value of metric to be created. In your case it should be `serviceResponseCode`.
- `value_label` name of the label, used if multiple columns are listed in `values` section, to distinguish between metrics corresponding to each of them. In this case it is not needed.

So to create metric

```
upload_document{serviceRequest="http://example.org/OTCS/llisapi.dll"} 200
```

you need configuration like

```yaml
collector_name: YYY

metrics:
  - metric_name: upload_document
    type: gauge
    help: 'Upload Document with REST API'
    key_labels:
      - serviceRequest
    values: [serviceResponseCode]
    query: |
      SELECT DISTINCT [serviceRequest], [serviceResponseCode]
      FROM [ccc].[bbb].[aaa]
      WHERE [serviceDisplayName] = 'UploadDoc'
```

Also please notice that it is expected for metric to contain unique set of labels. I'm not sure if sql_exporter ensures this, so I added a `DISTINCT`. But depending on you data structure, you might need to rework this query entirely to get only last result, not every unique pair.